# DNS resolve timeout on RHEL 6.3 behind firewall

Tags: domain-name-system, timeout, tcpdump, nslookup, dig

I have a server running Red Hat 6.3 Enterprise inside a VMWare virtual machine. There's a Juniper SSG 5 firewall sitting between the server and the Internet. I'm trying to diagnose what it looks like to be DNS lookup timeout but I'm afraid I don't have the knowledge required to do it.

Here's the output of tcpdump when I do a `$ wget www.google.com.br`:

```
$ tcpdump -i eth0 -n -vvv not port ssh

14:15:15.361010 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8975, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.12.54835 > 200.196.66.30.domain: [bad udp cksum f4e1!] 47797+ A? www.google.com.br. (35)
14:15:15.361195 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8976, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.12.54835 > 200.196.66.30.domain: [bad udp cksum 4e62!] 8028+ AAAA? www.google.com.br. (35)
14:15:15.362122 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 25375, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 283)
    200.196.66.30.domain > 192.168.1.12.54835: [udp sum ok] 47797 q: A? www.google.com.br. 4/4/4 www.google.com.br. [1m] CNAME www-cctld.l.google.com., www-cctld.l.google.com. [4m47s] A 74.125.234.184, www-cctld.l.google.com. [4m47s] A 74.125.234.191, www-cctld.l.google.com. [4m47s] A 74.125.234.183 ns: google.com. [20h11m12s] NS ns1.google.com., google.com. [20h11m12s] NS ns2.google.com., google.com. [20h11m12s] NS ns3.google.com., google.com. [20h11m12s] NS ns4.google.com. ar: ns1.google.com. [3d1h39m] A 216.239.32.10, ns2.google.com. [3d23h47m54s] A 216.239.34.10, ns3.google.com. [3d21h48m53s] A 216.239.36.10, ns4.google.com. [3d14h11m28s] A 216.239.38.10 (255)
14:15:20.365434 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8977, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.12.54835 > 200.196.66.30.domain: [bad udp cksum f4e1!] 47797+ A? www.google.com.br. (35)
14:15:20.366657 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 25377, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 283)
    200.196.66.30.domain > 192.168.1.12.54835: [udp sum ok] 47797 q: A? www.google.com.br. 4/4/4 www.google.com.br. [55s] CNAME www-cctld.l.google.com., www-cctld.l.google.com. [4m42s] A 74.125.234.191, www-cctld.l.google.com. [4m42s] A 74.125.234.183, www-cctld.l.google.com. [4m42s] A 74.125.234.184 ns: google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns4.google.com., google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns2.google.com., google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns3.google.com., google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns1.google.com. ar: ns1.google.com. [3d1h38m55s] A 216.239.32.10, ns2.google.com. [3d23h47m49s] A 216.239.34.10, ns3.google.com. [3d21h48m48s] A 216.239.36.10, ns4.google.com. [3d14h11m23s] A 216.239.38.10 (255)
14:15:20.366760 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8978, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.12.54835 > 200.196.66.30.domain: [bad udp cksum 4e62!] 8028+ AAAA? www.google.com.br. (35)
14:15:20.368486 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 25378, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 263)
    200.196.66.30.domain > 192.168.1.12.54835: [udp sum ok] 8028 q: AAAA? www.google.com.br. 2/4/4 www.google.com.br. [55s] CNAME www-cctld.l.google.com., www-cctld.l.google.com. [3m7s] AAAA 2800:3f0:4001:805::1017 ns: google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns3.google.com., google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns2.google.com., google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns4.google.com., google.com. [20h11m7s] NS ns1.google.com. ar: ns1.google.com. [3d1h38m55s] A 216.239.32.10, ns2.google.com. [3d23h47m49s] A 216.239.34.10, ns3.google.com. [3d21h48m48s] A 216.239.36.10, ns4.google.com. [3d14h11m23s] A 216.239.38.10 (235)
14:15:20.368936 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36272, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.1.12.58407 > 74.125.234.191.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xa695 (correct), seq 2103294767, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 499988127 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:15:20.370424 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 58, id 12210, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    74.125.234.191.http > 192.168.1.12.58407: Flags [S.], cksum 0x2a65 (correct), seq 1378505609, ack 2103294768, win 14180, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 4016826562 ecr 499988127,nop,wscale 6], length 0
[...]
```

The 5-second delay between the third and fourth lines happens consistently.

I *cannot* reproduce the delay using `nslookup`, `dig` or `dig +dnssec`, so I'm out of ideas.

Does anyone have any clue as to what could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens in dual stack IPv4/IPv6 environments where the machine doing a DNS lookup sends requests for AAAA and A records on the same socket, expecting to receive two replies back. This is [default behavior](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=505105) for relatively recent versions of glibc. The Juniper firewall, however, drops the connection after the first reply comes back.

The Juniper knowledge base has an article describing how to [configure the firewall to work around this issue](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB12312&actp=RSS).

As @BMDan noted, you can also add the line to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
options single-request-reopen
```

This works around the broken firewall behavior by opening two connections to look up the AAAA and A records.