# How do I set the single-request option in NetworkManager?

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, networkmanager

In our environment (lots of CentOS 7 VMs), we routinely encounter the oft-discussed issue where name service lookups result in a 5 second delay as a request times out, even on "successful" requests. As others have tried, we've disabled IPv6 (not used in our internal environment), and it didn't completely resolve the issue. Searching through the forums, we found the suggestion to add "options single-request" to /etc/resolv.conf; this *does* seem to fix the problem, but manual edits to resolv.conf are routinely overwritten by NetworkManager.

I've searched around, but I can't seem to find a place in nmtui or nmcli to specify this so that NetworkManager knows to include the option when it rewrites the file.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to set this somewhere else? Is there another, preferable fix for the issue?

Comment: The solution is to find and fix the broken firewall which is causing the problem.

Comment: Got a link / example?

Comment: That depends on the specific broken firewall, and you didn't mention what is in your environment. If you have a really old Juniper firewall, you might [read this](https://serverfault.com/a/411178/126632). It might have been sort of acceptable to use temporary workarounds for issues like this in 2012, but in 2018 it's inexcusable for firewalls to still be doing this.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to (and agree with) the notion that the right thing to do is to fix the problem at its source. However, I only have access to and control of the Linux VMs with which I'm working. The switches, firewalls, gateways and domain controllers are outside my control, and I don't even know the particulars. All I can do is nag the network infrastructure group. Hence the need to find workarounds that ARE within my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the *real* solution is to fix the AD server that handles DNS requests (my network admin is begging for an answer as to how), but in the meantime, I've found a workaround.

In /etc/sysconfig/network, add the following line:

RES_OPTIONS="single-request"

Comment: This answer does not work on my machine. (Using manjaro with NetworkManager 1.36.2-1.0)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add

```
dns  none
rc-manager  unmanaged
```

to the `[main]` section of your `/etc/networkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file. This should stop it from over-writing your resolver configuration. You can check out the options in the NetworkManager.conf man page on your system.

Comment: I was hoping to continue using the Network Manager to auto-configure rather than disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script to your `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatch.d/` folder though.

I have `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatch.d/999-resolv-options` (make sure it's owned by root, no setuid and `chmod`'ed to 700 though, according to [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html)):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

IFACE="$1"
ACTION="$2"

# Don't bother doing anything if action isn't "up"
if [ "$ACTION" != "up" ]; then
  exit
fi

case "$IFACE" in
  eth*|wlan*|en*)
    grep -q "options timeout 1" /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf &> /dev/null || echo "options timeout 1" >> /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
    grep -q "options single-request" /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf &> /dev/null || echo "options single-request" >> /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
    ;;
esac
```

*If your network interface names starts with something else than `eth*`, `en*` or `wlan*` then the case needs to be modified*

This will check if `options timeout 1` and `options single-request` exist, and if not, append them.

**Note**: the script appends to `/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` and not `/etc/resolv.conf`. On my Ubuntu 18.10 setup `/etc/resolv.conf` was symlinked to that file.

[More info about the `dispatch.d` abilities in the Network Manager docs.](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer NetworkManager service, then using **nmtui/nmcli** is better.
(the following cmds tested on centos7)

#### change setting (for those who suffering from 5s DNS delay problem)

`nmcli con modify YourConnName ipv4.dns-options "single-request-reopen timeout:2"`

> you can find YourConnName by executing : `nmcli con show`

#### apply setting

`nmcli con down YourConnName ; nmcli con up YourConnName`

#### P.S. change the setting to default, which is empty

`nmcli c m YourConnName ipv4.dns-options ''`

Answer (score 0):

The following answer works on Manjaro and also works for containers that are running on the host (unlike my previous answer). It is an adapted version of the answer from @carestad (Thank you!):

Place the following file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/999-resolv-options` and set the file permissions to `700` via `chmod`;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

IFACE="$1"
ACTION="$2"

declare -A expectedActions=( 
 [dhcp4-change]=1  [dhcp6-change]=1 [up]=1
)

# Don't bother doing anything if action isn't "dhcp4-change" or "dhcp6-change"
if [[ -z "${expectedActions[$ACTION]}" ]]; then
  exit
fi

case "$IFACE" in
  eth*|wlan*|en*|wlp2s*)
    grep -q "options single-request" /etc/resolv.conf &> /dev/null || echo "options single-request" >> /etc/resolv.conf
    ;;
esac
```

**Previous answer:**

It is possible to set the environment variable `RES_OPTIONS=single-request` globally in `/etc/environment`.

Note: The environment variable will be only effective on the host. Processes in containers are required to set this environment variable, too. The better solution is still to set the options in `/etc/resolv.conf` as the container runtime will usually inherit the `/etc/resolv.conf` from the host: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services